# How to get for each digit number of numbers that start with that digit from Java Stream?

Tags: java, text, java-stream, text-processing

I'm given a text that contains both numbers and words.

How do I get for each digit the number of numbers from the text that start with that digit?

I want to use Java Streams here.

I managed to filter all the numbers:

```
Files.lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file/text.txt"))
     .filter(Pattern.compile("\\d+").asPredicate())
```

But here comes the tough part. How do I calculate for each digit the number of numbers that starts with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could group by the initial character after filtering, and put the data into `Map<Character,Integer>`:

```
Map<Character,Integer> digCount = Files
    .lines(Paths.get("/path/to/file/text.txt"))
    .filter(Pattern.compile("\\d+").asPredicate())
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(s -> s.charAt(0), Collectors.summingInt(s->1)));
for (Map.Entry<Character,Integer> e : digCount.entrySet()) {
    System.out.println(e.getKey()+" "+e.getValue());
}
```

[Demo.](https://ideone.com/NYQgyG)